# Showing details on button click in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've three items in my page, each of them has its own button.
What I am trying to do is whenever a button is clicked, the details of the selected buttons should be shown inside .
I am completely new to this kind of programming situation.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <!------first item--->
    <div class="parentofitem">
    
     <div class="item_name">
      Item 1
     </div>
     <div class="item_price">
     100 
     </div>
     <div class="quantity">
      <input type="number" value="1" max="10"/>
     </div>
     <div class="addbut">
      <button class = "btn btn-default addwork" id="add1">ADD</button>
     </div>
    </div>
    <!------second item--->
    <div class="parentofitem">
    
     <div class="item_name">
      Item 2
     </div>
     <div class="item_price">
     180 
     </div>
     <div class="quantity">
      <input type="number" value="1" max="10"/>
     </div>
     <div class="addbut">
      <button class = "btn btn-default addwork" id="add2">ADD</button>
     </div>
    </div>
    <!------Third item--->
    <div class="parentofitem">
    
     <div class="item_name">
      Item 3
     </div>
     <div class="item_price">
     280 
     </div>
     <div class="quantity">
      <input type="number" value="1" max="10"/>
     </div>
     <div class="addbut">
      <button class = "btn btn-default addwork" id="add3">ADD</button>
     </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <aside>
     <div>Seleted items and there details should be shown here</div>
    </aside>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a reusable code that you can use to slove your issue , it also calculate the price , with a litle bit of styling it will look better :)

```js
item1={
 button:$(".addwork1"),
 name:$(".item_name1"),
 price:$(".item_price1"),
 quantity:$(".quantity1 >input"),
 result:$(".result1")

}
item2={
 button:$(".addwork2"),
 name:$(".item_name2"),
 price:$(".item_price2"),
 quantity:$(".quantity2 >input"),
  result:$(".result2")

}
item3={
 button:$(".addwork3"),
 name:$(".item_name3"),
 price:$(".item_price3"),
 quantity:$(".quantity3 >input"),
 result:$(".result3")
}

function getresult(data){
data.button.on("click",()=>{
data.result.text("The :" + data.name.text() + 
                   " The total price: "+ (data.price.text() * data.quantity.val()) + 
                   " Quantity: " + data.quantity.val() )
})
}

getresult(item1);
getresult(item2);
getresult(item3);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
<!------first item--->
<div class="parentofitem">

    <div class="item_name1">
        Item 1
    </div>
    <div class="item_price1">
    100 
    </div>
    <div class="quantity1">
        <input type="number" value="1" max="10"/>
    </div>
    <div class="addbut">
        <button class = "btn btn-default addwork1" id="add1">ADD</button>
        <div class="result1"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<!------second item--->
<div class="parentofitem">

    <div class="item_name2">
        Item 2
    </div>
    <div class="item_price2">
    180 
    </div>
    <div class="quantity2">
        <input type="number" value="1" max="10"/>
    </div>
    <div class="addbut">
        <button class = "btn btn-default addwork2" id="add2">ADD</button>
        <div class="result2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<!------Third item--->
<div class="parentofitem">

    <div class="item_name3">
        Item 3
    </div>
    <div class="item_price3">
    280 
    </div>
    <div class="quantity3">
        <input type="number" value="1" max="10"/>
    </div>
    <div class="addbut">
        <button class = "btn btn-default addwork3" id="add3">ADD</button>
        <div class="result3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes this is correct , but i want if another button is clicked after a button ,its details should be shown in next line

Comment: @pyrogrammer I am glad i was able to help you :)